# How to run a number of Observables in series

Tags: javascript, typescript, observable, rxjs5

Given a list of inputs in an array I want to run a sync tasks that returns an observable. But I need these tasks to run consecutively not in parallel. As you can see below all the tasks are started at the same time.

My second question is how to accumulate the results of each iteration of fakeAsyncWork in a array to be returned at the end. Clearly my scan in at the wrong place at the moment.

Here is jsbin: http://jsbin.com/kujilow/15/edit?js,console

```
const source$ = Rx.Observable.of(1,2,3,4)

const job$ = source$
  .do(x=>console.log("emitted from source " + x))
   .switchMap(n => fakeAsyncWork(n))
  .do(x=>console.log("emitted from switch " + x))
  .scan((a,c) => a.concat(c), [])


let fakeAsyncWork = (sec): Rx.Observable<any> => {
  return  new Rx.Observable(observer => {
          console.log("start waiting for " + sec);
          setTimeout(() => {
                console.log("finish waiting " + sec);
                observer.next(sec*10)
            }, sec*1000);

  });
}

job$.subscribe(x => console.log(x) );
```

Current results:

```
"emitted from source 1"
"start waiting for 1"
"emitted from source 2"
"start waiting for 2"
"emitted from source 3"
"start waiting for 3"
"emitted from source 4"
"start waiting for 4"
"finish waiting 1"
"finish waiting 2"
"finish waiting 3"
"finish waiting 4"
"emitted from switch 40"
[40]
```

Desired results: (Each task is finished before the next one is started)

```
"emitted from source 1"
"start waiting for 1"
"finish waiting 1"
"emitted from source 2"
"start waiting for 2"
"finish waiting 2"
"emitted from source 3"
"start waiting for 3"
"finish waiting 3"
"emitted from source 4"
"start waiting for 4"
"finish waiting 4"
"emitted from switch [10,20,30,40]"
[10,20,30,40]
```

Cheers :=)

Comment: `const job$ = source$.concatMap(n => fakeAsyncWork(n)).toArrray();`

Comment: unfortunately that does not work. Here you can see http://jsbin.com/kujilow/16/edit?js,console  I added the desired output in the question to make it more clear.

Comment: The problem is that your fake observable does not complete. If you are working with observables that don't complete and you only want the first emitted value, use `first()` or `take(1)`: `const job$ = source$.concatMap(n => fakeAsyncWork(n).take(1)).toArrray();`

Comment: Wow. I can't thank you enough Nicholas. I was going crazy. If you ever happen to come to seattle or I end up in Australia I would buy you a beer. :-)